# Retrofit + RxJava Not making API Request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have an issue with Retrofit and RxJava2 in Kotlin.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.1' implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.8.0'

// RxJava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.11'
```

I have the following Retrofit interface with a single request, `login`. I also have a simple `data class` called `User`.

```
data class User (
    private val firstName: String
)

interface ApiService {
    @POST("auth/login")
    fun login(@Body body: String) : Observable<User>
}
```

When I try to make a request and subscribe to it, no request is being sent. I have checked my server logs and the server is not receiving anything at all. There are also no errors in the app logs. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong since I've looked at many articles/tutorials and they all said to do it this way.

```
val client = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://example.com/api/")
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapaterFactory.create())
    .build()
    .create(ApiService::class.java)

client.login(JSONObject().put("email", ...).toString())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe()
```

Could anyone explain to me what I'm actually doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I have tried the follow code and I still get the same result. No request is made.

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(
    HttpLoggingInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger.DEFAULT)
).build()

val client = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://example.com/api/")
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build()
    .create(ApiClient::class.java)

client.login(JSONObject().put("email", ...).toString())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ user -> println(user) }, { error -> println(error) })
```

Comment: Remove last / from baseurl 
baseUrl("https://example.com/api")

or first / from
 @POST("auth/login")

from any of one place. not from both

Comment: It's still not making the API request. I already tried that before.

Comment: Add `onError` implementation to the `subscribe(..)` function and log the errors

Comment: Are you suggesting `.subscribeBy(onError = { throwable -> Log.e(throwable.toString()) })`, because that logs absolutely nothing to the console.

Comment: First try following this simple example from retrofit's documentation and make a request to github's api. https://square.github.io/retrofit/ `https://api.github.com/users/{users}/repos`. WHen you have successfully made retrofit work, change apis to your own server. If something is wrong after that, then it's a server issue.

Comment: It doesn't even work with github's api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to add a Moshi converter to your retrofit instance.

```
.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
```

Comment: Retrofit uses okhttpclient by default if nothing is provided. Therefore, that is probably not the issue here

Comment: if you're using moshi you should add its converter to your retrofit instance .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())

Comment: I just saw moshi dependency, did you add that?

Comment: What the? I have been trying to fix this issue for 10 hours and it was 1 line? This really goes to show how important sleep is :) If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a logging interceptor to see the logs.

```
val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()

val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapaterFactory.create())  

val apiService = builder.client(httpClient).build().create(ApiService::class.java)
```

I assume that you add INTERNET permission to AndroidManifest.xml

As @sonnet suggests, you should add callbacks to your requests

```
apiService.login(JSONObject().put("email", ...).toString())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ user -> ... }, { error -> ... })
```

Comment: After adding an interceptor and callbacks, it hasn't changed anything. Nothing is logged to the console, and no request is made.

Comment: @Dante Do you have internet connection on emulator or device? :)